# Variable inside of a component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, variables

I'll try to explain my question through an example.

If I have something like this in my new component:

```
    ... implements OnInit {
    constructor( ... ) { }
    variable = "";
    ngOnInit(): void {
      ...
    }
```

Then I can use my `variable` inside of the ngOnInit with `this.`, like so:

```
this.variable = '1';
```

But how can I use my variable inside of a child function of the ngOnInit? For example:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
      ...
      // here I want to use another function with my `variable`
      // something like:
      // myFunc() {
      // this.variable = '2';
      // }
      ...
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just use arrow function and you're good as it automatically bind itself to  `this`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  let somefunc: any = () => {
      this.variable = "got here";
  };
}
```

hope that helps